# Restore MS SQL 2008 Database from files

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, restore, sql-server-2008

is it possible to restore a MSSQL server by copying its directory/data files? I have a damaged hard disk and was able to salvage the C:\Program Files (x86)\SQL Server 2008\MSSQL\MSSQL10.MYDATABASE directory. I copied that to my new installation and tried to start the service, but it failed. Is it possible so retore the db somehow?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit and MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restore a database from the files you need the data file - MDF, sometimes NDF exist as well, and the log file - LDF.

1. Start SQL Server Management Studio
2. Right-click the **Databases** node
3. Select **Attach**
4. Click **Add**
5. Select the MDF file you saved
6. The LDF file should be automatically added. If not, the 'Not found' message will be shown and you must add the file manually by clicking the ellipsis button

[image]

If this fails, try to attach only the MDF file, using the [sp_attach_single_file_db](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174385%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'AdventureWorks2012Restored' ,
@physname = N'D:\ApexSQL\backups\CS2.mdf';
```

If this fails, the MDF file might be corrupted. You can try a third party tool that will read the MDF file and recover your data

[ApexSQL Recover](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_recover.aspx) is a tool that can read a corrupted MDF file, re-create all objects and recover table records. It can create T-SQL script or create a copy of the database

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a support engineer*

Answer (score 4):

1. You shouldn't have copied the entire directory. You should have copied only the database and transaction log files for the database in question.
2. Uninstall and reinstall SQL Server on the target host.
3. Copy the database and transaction log files for the database in question to the target host.
4. Attach the database.

Comment: What joeqwerty said.  Generally, you want to be cautious about copying the system databases over each other.  More specifically: Master contains the server's information about the databases themselves, including the location of the files.  MSDB contains any jobs you had.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what @joeqwerty said, just few tips for the future.

It is best to keep database files .MDF on separate drive from log files .LDF. It is also recommended to keep all databases off the C: drive. TEMPDB performs best when it is on a drive by it self.

Here is an article how to move system dbs [Tech Net](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx)

Comment: Just to clarify: SQL Server transaction logs do not have the .LOG file extension, they have the .LDF file extension.